# Invalid Argument Error Tensorflow Object Detection Training

Tags: tensorflow, rgb, tensor, object-recognition

I am training tensor flow object detection following the tensor flow API. I have trained many models in the past using the exact same steps. This model however keeps giving me the error message below. The error message references

InvalidArgumentError: image_size must contain 3 elements[4]

I searched the error and found

[InvalidArgumentError: image_size must contain 3 elements[4] #3349](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3349)

which shows the error and gives the solution of checking to make sure that all images are RGB. I used the code provided in that thread to check all images. I found about 15 images that were not RGB. I removed the images and the corresponding xml files. I recompiled the csv files and the tfrecord files and restarted the training. I received the error message again. I then tried to start the training over without resuming from the last checkpoint and I still received the error. The error does not happen on a regular basis. Sometimes the model will go for several thousand steps before a failure. I have also tried removing the random crop parameter from the pipeline.config file which had no affect.

Any help is appreciated.

Error Message:

```
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 2.03361
INFO:tensorflow:global step 4039: loss = 6.2836 (0.512 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>, image_size must contain 3 elements[4]
         [[Node: cond_2/RandomCropImage/sample_distorted_bounding_box/SampleDistortedBoundingBoxV2 = SampleDistortedBoundingBoxV2[T=DT_INT32, area_range=[0.1, 1], aspect_ratio_range=[0.5, 2],max_attempts=100, seed=0, seed2=0, use_image_if_no_bounding_boxes=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](cond_2/RandomCropImage/Shape, cond_2/RandomCropImage/ExpandDims, cond_2/RandomCropImage/PruneNonOverlappingBoxes/Const)]]
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 4039.
INFO:tensorflow:global step 4040: loss = 4.6984 (0.880 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:Finished training! Saving model to disk.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/floyd/object_detection/legacy/train.py", line 184, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, inrun
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 250, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/floyd/object_detection/legacy/train.py", line 180, in main
    graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
  File "/floyd/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py", line 415, in train
    saver=saver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 785, in train
    ignore_live_threads=ignore_live_threads)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 833, in stop
    ignore_live_threads=ignore_live_threads)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line389, in join
    six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/queue_runner_impl.py", line 252, in _run
    enqueue_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1244,in _single_operation_run
    self._call_tf_sessionrun(None, {}, [], target_list, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1409,in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: image_size must contain 3 elements[4]
         [[Node: cond_2/RandomCropImage/sample_distorted_bounding_box/SampleDistortedBoundingBoxV2 = SampleDistortedBoundingBoxV2[T=DT_INT32, area_range=[0.1, 1], aspect_ratio_range=[0.5, 2],max_attempts=100, seed=0, seed2=0, use_image_if_no_bounding_boxes=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](cond_2/RandomCropImage/Shape, cond_2/RandomCropImage/ExpandDims, cond_2/RandomCropImage/PruneNonOverlappingBoxes/Const)]]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

so it was the RGB image problem. I had checked the images and removed the non RGB images and recreated the records, but the model was still pointing to the old records because the paths were very similar, I did not notice.